# What message is sent when you minimize a window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm catching `WindowProc` and looking for `WM_SYSCOMMAND` / `SC_MINIMIZE`, but it only fires the message when I minimize the window by clicking in its taskbar icon.

When I click in the window's minimize button the message isn't fired.

```
switch (Msg)
{
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case SC_MINIMIZE:
        {
            OutputDebugStringW(L"Window minimized!");
            //return TRUE;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

I noticed that my window was not sending the `WM_SIZE` message, then while searching i have found this:

> By default, the DefWindowProc function sends the WM_SIZE and WM_MOVE messages to the window. The WM_SIZE and WM_MOVE messages are not sent if an application handles the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message without calling DefWindowProc. It is more efficient to perform any move or size change processing during the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message without calling DefWindowProc.

I confirmed that its sending `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` when i try to minimize by clicking in the minimize button.

```cpp
    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:

        tagWINDOWPOS * wp    = reinterpret_cast<tagWINDOWPOS *>(lParam);
        wp->x = ...;
        wp->y = ...;
        wp->cx = ...;
        wp->cy = ...;

        LPARAM lp    = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(wp);
```

I have tried to set `x, y, cx, cy` values to the current ones, but the window still got minimized.

Comment: The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) says: `In WM_SYSCOMMAND messages, the four low-order bits of the wParam parameter are used internally by the system. To obtain the correct result when testing the value of wParam, an application must combine the value 0xFFF0 with the wParam value by using the bitwise AND operator.`. I don't know if it is the issue root cause here but you should use `wParam & 0xFFF0` value when checking the command code.

Answer (score 3):

The [`WM_SIZE` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size) is sent to a window when its size has been changed; if that size change was to minimize the window, then the `wParam` argument will be `SIZE_MINIMIZED`. (This `WM_SIZE` will also be sent after the `WM_SYSCOMMAND`/`SC_MINIMIZE` combination, so you can detect the minimize operation, no matter what user action triggered it.)

So, your code in the `WndProc` would be along these lines:

```cpp
    switch (Msg) {
        case WM_SIZE:
            switch (wParam) {
                case SIZE_MINIMIZED:
                    OutputDebugStringW(L"Window minimized!");
                //  return TRUE;
                    break;
                //...
            }
            break;

            //...
    }
```

Comment: Adrian Mole, i have add new info into the topic, could you take a look?

Comment: @Threensy I have looked into using/intercepting the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` but I can't find any way to know from that message if the window is being minimized.

Comment: When its minimizing `x` and `y` are negative values inside of `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, but i dont think will be possible to intercept it from minimizing this way :/

Comment: @Threensy Hmm. Those x and y are also both negative for maximizing ... which can be prevented by setting the `flags` member to `SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE`. Still no joy for preventing the minimize though. Working ...

Comment: @Threensy Also, your original idea seems pretty close. Just `return 0;` when you get the `WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_MINIMIZE` combination ... but you ***must*** then let the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` handler call `DefWindowProc` ... or, as you've discovered, that message isn't sent at all.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean `Just return 0; when you get the WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_MINIMIZE` but it doesnt receive the message,

Comment: @Threensy Then I can't reproduce: My (very basic) windows app has a WndProc that **does** receive the message. Maybe there's something else in your WndProc that's messing up the system.